# <ul> and <p> not wrapping in css grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to understand the CSS grid layout and I love every bit of it so far! However, I can't seem to get the code blow to work.

When the nav sidebar fills the whole width, I want the paragraph to the right to break down beneath the navigation. I know how I'd do it with flexbox and media queries (flex-direction: row vs column) but I don't really get how one does it with CSS grid. Can you help me?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


/* Navigation */

.legal-navi {
  grid-column: 1;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.legal-navi li {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* border */
  border: black solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.legal-navi li a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.legal-navi li:last-child {
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
}


/* content */

.legal-content {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="legal-navi">
    <li>
      <a href="lorem">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ipsum">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="dolor">Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ahmet">Ahmet</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="legal-content">
    Cry louder at reflection eat half my food and ask for more so dont wait for the storm to pass, dance in the rain for tweeting a baseball poop on floor and watch human clean up lick the plastic bag but stand with legs in litter box, but poop outside. Stand
    with legs in litter box, but poop outside cats are fats i like to pets them they like to meow back, twitch tail in permanent irritation so immediately regret falling into bathtub yet nyan fluffness ahh cucumber!, but the door is opening! how exciting
    oh, it's you, meh purr while eating. When in doubt, wash eat owner's food so sit in a box for hours and skid on floor, crash into wall pretend not to be evil. Give attitude if human is on laptop sit on the keyboard so demand to have some of whatever
    the human is cooking, then sniff the offering and walk away, cat slap dog in face. Hide from vacuum cleaner purrr purr littel cat, little cat purr purr or eat the fat cats food. Eat an easter feather as if it were a bird then burp victoriously, but
    tender pee in human's bed until he cleans the litter box sleep in the bathroom sink sleep nap but furrier and even more furrier hairball cat gets stuck in tree firefighters try to get cat down firefighters get stuck in tree cat eats firefighters'
    slippers. Weigh eight pounds but take up a full-size bed poop on grasses but scream for no reason at 4 am, sleep nap plays league of legends sit on human they not getting up ever for my slave human didn't give me any food so i pooped on the floor.
    Meow. Meow for food, then when human fills food dish, take a few bites of food and continue meowing cat fur is the new black cat fur is the new black , cough hairball, eat toilet paper grab pompom in mouth and put in water dish for stare out cat door
    then go back inside i love cats i am one wake up scratch humans leg for food then purr then i have a and relax. Annoy kitten brother with poking. Curl up and sleep on the freshly laundered towels eat too much then proceed to regurgitate all over living
    room carpet while humans eat dinner, for sit on human sleep everywhere, but not in my bed i show my fluffy belly but it's a trap! if you pet it i will tear up your hand and sit on human they not getting up ever. Mewl for food at 4am x intently sniff
    hand cat milk copy park pee walk owner escape bored tired cage droppings sick vet vomit but show belly nyan fluffness ahh cucumber! so you call this cat food. Meowing chowing and wowing then cats take over the world for chase ball of string for being
    gorgeous with belly side up. Why use post when this sofa is here milk the cow or favor packaging over toy pet my belly, you know you want to; seize the hand and shred it!. Sniff sniff chew on cable stare at owner accusingly then wink for eat the rubberband,
    asdflkjaertvlkjasntvkjn (sits on keyboard) the door is opening! how exciting oh, it's you, meh. Eat prawns daintily with a claw then lick paws clean wash down prawns with a lap of carnation milk then retire to the warmest spot on the couch to claw
    at the fabric before taking a catnap. Poop in a handbag look delicious and drink the soapy mopping up water then puke giant foamy fur-balls hide head under blanket so no one can see hate dog, so human give me attention meow i can haz. Behind the couch
    climb leg, so sun bathe. Ask to be pet then attack owners hand sleep on dog bed, force dog to sleep on floor lies down , for rub butt on table. Mew chase ball of string so scratch at fleas, meow until belly rubs, hide behind curtain when vacuum cleaner
    is on scratch strangers and poo on owners food, yet intently stare at the same spot, yet plays league of legends mesmerizing birds for cat jumps and falls onto the couch purrs and wakes up in a new dimension filled with kitty litter meow meow yummy
    there is a bunch of cats hanging around eating catnip . Scratch at fleas, meow until belly rubs, hide behind curtain when vacuum cleaner is on scratch strangers and poo on owners food my left donut is missing, as is my right but give me some of your
    food give me some of your food give me some of your food meh, i don't want it i is not fat, i is fluffy, but i like big cats and i can not lie, but lick face hiss at owner, pee a lot, and meow repeatedly scratch at fence purrrrrr eat muffins and poutine
    until owner comes back. Lick sellotape find empty spot in cupboard and sleep all day destroy the blinds and stare at owner accusingly then wink ccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttttttttssssssssssssssss but kitty pounce, trip, faceplant you didn't
    see that no you didn't definitely didn't lick, lick, lick, and preen away the embarrassment for mesmerizing birds. Shove bum in owner's face like camera lens Gate keepers of hell or i heard this rumor where the humans are our owners, pfft, what do
    they know?!.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you brief about the issue in detail?

Comment: Basically what I wrote in my OP - I want the paragraph to be below the nav-bar (ul) when the screen gets smaller :)

Comment: What's wrong with media queries and CSS-Grid? CSS-Grid is not a magic alternative to media queries, you still have to use them to change the layout,

Comment: the culprit is this one: grid-column: 2 / -1; .You explicitely defined the element to take the second column so it will never wrap

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's totally it! Can you post that as an actual answer so I can upvote it and mark it as the solution? Feel free to take my code and modify it! Also, how do I make paragraph span across the remaining width without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitely defined the `grid-column` to be `2` so this won't happen. By the way, such task isn't suitable with CSS grid if you don't want to use media query.

You can do it with flexbox and without media query like below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.legal-navi {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.legal-content {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  min-width: 250px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/**/

.legal-navi li {
  width: 100%;
  border: black solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.legal-navi li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.legal-navi li:last-child {
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="legal-navi">
    <li>
      <a href="lorem">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ipsum">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="dolor">Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ahmet">Ahmet</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="legal-content">
    Cry louder at reflection eat half my food and ask for more so dont wait for the storm to pass, dance in the rain for tweeting a baseball poop on floor and watch human clean up lick the plastic bag but stand with legs in litter box, but poop outside. Stand
    with legs in litter box, but poop outside cats are fats i like to pets them they like to meow back, twitch tail in permanent irritation so immediately regret falling into bathtub yet nyan fluffness ahh cucumber!, but the door is opening! how exciting
    oh, it's you, meh purr while eating. When in doubt, wash eat owner's food so sit in a box for hours and skid on floor, crash into wall pretend not to be evil. Give attitude if human is on laptop sit on the keyboard so demand to have some of whatever
    the human is cooking, then sniff the offering and walk away, cat slap dog in face. Hide from vacuum cleaner purrr purr littel cat, little cat purr purr or eat the fat cats food. Eat an easter feather as if it were a bird then burp victoriously, but
    tender pee in human's bed until he cleans the litter box sleep in the bathroom sink sleep nap but furrier and even more furrier hairball cat gets stuck in tree firefighters try to get cat down firefighters get stuck in tree cat eats firefighters'
    slippers. Weigh eight pounds but take up a full-size bed poop on grasses but scream for no reason at 4 am, sleep nap plays league of legends sit on human they not getting up ever for my slave human didn't give me any food so i pooped on the floor.
    Meow. Meow for food, then when human fills food dish, take a few bites of food and continue meowing cat fur is the new black cat fur is the new black , cough hairball, eat toilet paper grab pompom in mouth and put in water dish for stare out cat door
    then go back inside i love cats i am one wake up scratch humans leg for food then purr then i have a and relax. Annoy kitten brother with poking. Curl up and sleep on the freshly laundered towels eat too much then proceed to regurgitate all over living
    room carpet while humans eat dinner, for sit on human sleep everywhere, but not in my bed i show my fluffy belly but it's a trap! if you pet it i will tear up your hand and sit on human they not getting up ever. Mewl for food at 4am x intently sniff
    hand cat milk copy park pee walk owner escape bored tired cage droppings sick vet vomit but show belly nyan fluffness ahh cucumber! so you call this cat food. Meowing chowing and wowing then cats take over the world for chase ball of string for being
    gorgeous with belly side up. Why use post when this sofa is here milk the cow or favor packaging over toy pet my belly, you know you want to; seize the hand and shred it!. Sniff sniff chew on cable stare at owner accusingly then wink for eat the rubberband,
    asdflkjaertvlkjasntvkjn (sits on keyboard) the door is opening! how exciting oh, it's you, meh. Eat prawns daintily with a claw then lick paws clean wash down prawns with a lap of carnation milk then retire to the warmest spot on the couch to claw
    at the fabric before taking a catnap. Poop in a handbag look delicious and drink the soapy mopping up water then puke giant foamy fur-balls hide head under blanket so no one can see hate dog, so human give me attention meow i can haz. Behind the couch
    climb leg, so sun bathe. Ask to be pet then attack owners hand sleep on dog bed, force dog to sleep on floor lies down , for rub butt on table. Mew chase ball of string so scratch at fleas, meow until belly rubs, hide behind curtain when vacuum cleaner
    is on scratch strangers and poo on owners food, yet intently stare at the same spot, yet plays league of legends mesmerizing birds for cat jumps and falls onto the couch purrs and wakes up in a new dimension filled with kitty litter meow meow yummy
    there is a bunch of cats hanging around eating catnip . Scratch at fleas, meow until belly rubs, hide behind curtain when vacuum cleaner is on scratch strangers and poo on owners food my left donut is missing, as is my right but give me some of your
    food give me some of your food give me some of your food meh, i don't want it i is not fat, i is fluffy, but i like big cats and i can not lie, but lick face hiss at owner, pee a lot, and meow repeatedly scratch at fence purrrrrr eat muffins and poutine
    until owner comes back. Lick sellotape find empty spot in cupboard and sleep all day destroy the blinds and stare at owner accusingly then wink ccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttttttttssssssssssssssss but kitty pounce, trip, faceplant you didn't
    see that no you didn't definitely didn't lick, lick, lick, and preen away the embarrassment for mesmerizing birds. Shove bum in owner's face like camera lens Gate keepers of hell or i heard this rumor where the humans are our owners, pfft, what do
    they know?!.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why isn't it suitable with grid? It seemed like a perfect use case for it

Comment: @VADS without media query you cannot do this with CSS grid. Wrapping isn't the best of CSS grid, it's a perfect case for flexbox

Answer (score -2):

I think you can take a look at how it's solved in bootstrap.
The sidebar does not expand at all.
See what they consist of and when to use classes:

- container
  This class should have a dunamic width depending on the @mediaquery settings.
- row
  you also need to do something to separate the lines. Read how the row class works.

In general, the bootstrap documentation itself refers to the page:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background

There you have this topic explained on pure CSS - and that's probably what you mean...

An example of a grid with used mediaquery

```
<style>
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%; /* The width is 20%, by default */
}

.main {
  float: left;
  width: 60%; /* The width is 60%, by default */
}

/* Use a media query to add a breakpoint at 800px: */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .left, .main, .right {
    width: 100%; /* The width is 100%, when the viewport is 800px or smaller */
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately not looking for a solution in bootstrap or flexbox, but in CSS grid :) like the 'display: grid' thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout